# Windows 10: Open file directories with a custom application by default

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Since everything I see is `explorer.exe`, I labelled different parts of it in the screenshots at the bottom, to make it easy to understand.

**TL;DR**

1. Can I make my own application open directories by default when I click a directory in "1" or "2"?
2. With the change for the question above, can I still make double-clicking a directory in a manually-opened "3" open in the same "3", not with my application?

**Longer version**

There are some incontinences for me in "3". So I am trying to write a (simple) my own file listing application in C#. Now, what I want is that when I double click a directory on the desktop or clicking things like "Downloads" or "Personal Folder" (in "1" or "2"), my own application gets invoked (with the directory path as an argument), not "3".

I have searched the web and found a way to "replace the shell" `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell`, but that completely replaced everything and the Start Menu/Taskbar were gone. Not that I do not have complaints about the Start Menu/Taskbar, but recreating Start Menu/Taskbar would be daunting, so I only want to replace "3" (or, if possible, "1" also.)

I thought that I could change the "Open" command that I see when I right-click a directory, but replacing the value of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command\(Default)` from `explorer.exe` to another exe did not work. How can I do this?

But after making my application to open directories by default, if I manually open directories in "3" (because I cannot reproduce every feature of "3" and sometimes need to use it), when I double-click a directory in "3", is it possible to make it open in the same "3", not with my application?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think what you want to achieve would require rewriting/hacking the explorer.exe code. You can add your own right-click menu commands, though.

Comment: You're referring to two things, depending on the end goal: `Explorer.exe` is the [Windows Shell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-entry), with File Explorer being apart of the Windows Shell. There are File Explorer replacements (Xyplorer, TotalCommander, QDir, etc.), however all lack modern UI improvements and you will not find a consumer File Explorer replacement that fits aesthetically into Windows >8. There are also Windows Shell [replacements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows) with the same pitfalls as File Explorer replacements

Comment: _Cont'd..._ It is possible to modify `Explorer.exe`, however the modified `Explorer.exe` would need to reside outside of `%WinDir%`, else it will not match hashes and be seen as corrupt _(never replace system files with custom modified ones)_, and if you go this route, you'll want to check out the [MSFN Forum](https://msfn.org/board/). You'll want to keep detailed notes about what you customize, as you'll regularly need to check if `%WinDir%\explorer.exe` has been updated and re-edit as necessary. Keep a read-only text file with the modified `Explorer.exe` SHA256 hash and verify it daily.

Comment: @JW0914 Yeah, I have already tried almost all free file explorer applications. All of them handled high DPI badly (to small). That is why I wanted to create my own file listing application. Modifying `Explorer.exe` sounds very complicated and will probably cause a lot of problems in the future. I don't know... writing the whole thing (Start menu, Taskbar) myself seems too much of a work. If there is no easy way to replace "3" only, I would have to resort to launch the application manually instead of double clicking a directory in "1" or "2".

Comment: @DamnVegetables By "modify `Explorer.exe`" I was referring to File Explorer specifically, as while both have the same name, File Explorer is it's own entity (it's both apart of, and separate from, the Windows Shell _(I forgot to add the last bit in my prior comment)_. Check out the MSFN forum, as I know of at least one user on there who's modfied File Explorer, adding in a feature that was in Windows 7, but removed from Windows 8 and 10. MSFN is all about in-depth customizing of Windows.